# How to use "explain" for _search queries in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 2.3.3.

I have the following mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "entries": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
            "Data": {
                "properties": {
                    "FirstName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following query:

```
POST /frm4356/entries/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {"Data.FirstName" : "BBB"}
    }
}
```

Which works fine and yields the following response:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "frm4356_v3",
        "_type": "entries",
        "_id": "57c867715f7ecd2a78610ec6",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Data": {
            "FirstName": "BBB"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to used the "Explain API" but failed miserably.

The following did not work:

**Attempt #1**

```
POST /frm4356/entries/_explain
{
    "query" : {
    "match" : {"Data.FirstName" : "BBB"}
    }
}
```

**Attempt #2:**

```
POST /frm4356/entries/_search
{
    "explain" : true,
    "query" : {
    "match" : {"Data.FirstName" : "BBB"}
    }
}
```

In both cases, I keep getting this response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "strict_dynamic_mapping_exception",
            "reason": "mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [query] within [entries] is not allowed"
         }
      ],
      "type": "strict_dynamic_mapping_exception",
      "reason": "mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [query] within [entries] is not allowed"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? I'd like to see the explanation of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
GET /blog/post/_validate/query?explain
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "Smith"
    }
  }
}
```

[Source](http://elasticsearch-cheatsheet.jolicode.com/")

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) the official documentation for Explain API.

It looks like you missed the _id there.

```
POST /frm4356/entries/57c867715f7ecd2a78610ec6/_explain
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Data.FirstName": "BBB"
    }
  }
}
```